# Return the indices of a 3D array in R based on multiple values

Tags: arrays, r

I would like to obtain the indices of a 3D array in R (ie. arr[x,y,z]) based on multiple values.  Specifically, using the first z dimension to subset values in the second z dimension.  Here is a example:

```
 # create example array
 > m1 <- matrix(c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5), rep("c",5)), nr = 5)  
 > m2 <- matrix(c(rep(100, 5), rep(10, 5), rep(10, 5)), nr = 5)
 > arr <- array(c(m1, m2), dim = c(dim(m1), 2))

 #use which() to return the indices in m2 that correspond to indices with
 #"a" and "c" values in m1.  This does not work as expected.
 > ac.ind <- which(arr[,,1] %in% c("a", "c"), arr.ind = T)

 > ac.ind
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5 11 12 13 14 15
```

which() returns an vector of positions in m1 that correspond to "a" and "c", not the matrix indices (the (x,y) positions). I would like ac.ind to return:

```
           row col
      [1,]   1   1
      [2,]   2   1
      [3,]   3   1
      [4,]   4   1
      [5,]   5   1
      [1,]   1   3
      [2,]   2   3
      [3,]   3   3
      [4,]   4   3
      [5,]   5   3
```

If I do a more simple which() subset, it does return the indices:

```
 #use which to return indices in m2 that correspond to only "a" in m1
 >a.ind <- which(arr[,,1] == c("a"), arr.ind = T)

 >a.ind
      row col
 [1,]   1   1
 [2,]   2   1
 [3,]   3   1
 [4,]   4   1
 [5,]   5   1
```

I am using %in% since I want to subset based on two values in m1 ("a" and "c" values).  Is there a way to return the indices of an array based on two values in R?

Comment: See, also, `?arrayInd`; `arrayInd(ac.ind, dim(arr)[1:2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `arr[,,1] %in% c("a", "c")` returns a vector. One way is to cast this as a `matrix` with the number of rows equaling the first dimension of `arr`:

```
ac.ind <- which(matrix(arr[,,1] %in% c("a", "c"), nrow=dim(arr)[1]), arr.ind = T)
##      row col
## [1,]   1   1
## [2,]   2   1
## [3,]   3   1
## [4,]   4   1
## [5,]   5   1
## [6,]   1   3
## [7,]   2   3
## [8,]   3   3
## [9,]   4   3
##[10,]   5   3
```

Comment: Thanks!  this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this but it is not very efficient because it has to go twice through the data:

```
ac.ind <- which(arr[,,1] == "c" | arr[,,1] == "a" , arr.ind = T)

ac.ind

          row col
     [1,]   1   1
     [2,]   2   1
     [3,]   3   1
     [4,]   4   1
     [5,]   5   1
     [6,]   1   3
     [7,]   2   3
     [8,]   3   3
     [9,]   4   3
    [10,]   5   3
```